# Angular 9 Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at MatSelect.ngAfterContentInit for Mat Paginator

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9

I'm getting the following error while running a component with mat-paginator in Angular version 9. My html and typescript files are as below.
The left, right pages as well as first and last buttons are working in the paginator, but the select for items per page is not unresponsive due to the following error for mat-select.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at MatSelect.ngAfterContentInit (core.js:formatted:1)
    at callHook (core.js:formatted:43741)
    at callHooks (core.js:formatted:43705)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:formatted:43647)
    at refreshView (core.js:formatted:1)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:formatted:1)
    at refreshView (core.js:formatted:1)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:formatted:1)
    at refreshView (core.js:formatted:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:formatted:1)
```

```js
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
        // import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
        import { DataserviceService } from 'src/app/dataservice.service';
        import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
        import {  BalanceInquiryModel } from 'src/app/services/model.interface';
        import { DataProvider } from 'src/app/services/dataprovider';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-bi-recent-report',
          templateUrl: './bi-recent-report.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./bi-recent-report.component.css']
        })
        export class BIRecentReportComponent implements OnInit {

          showTable: boolean;
          dataSource;
          getby: string;
          blob: Blob;
          isClicked1: boolean = false;
          isClicked2: boolean = false;


          constructor( private service: DataserviceService, public dataProvider: DataProvider)  { }
          @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
          @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

          displayedColumns = ["id", "adhaarNumber", "bankName","errorMessage","requestedTimestamp","fingpayTransactionId","responseRrn","latitude","longitude","deviceImei","superMerchantName","branchname","branchLoginId","merchantName","merchantLoginId","phoneNumber","requestedRemarks","responseRemarks","stan","responseTime","responseDate","responseCode","cardAcceptorTerminalIdentification","transactionIdentifier","webStatus","merchantId","responseCardAcceptorTerminalIdentification","resposeTimestamp","responseAccountIdentification"];

          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getTableData();

          }

          applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
            filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
            filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
            this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
          }

          getDisplayedColumns() {
            return this.displayedColumns;
          }

          getTableData() {
            this.service.getBIRecentReport().subscribe(

            response => {
              var myjson = JSON.stringify(response);
              var array=  JSON.parse(myjson);

                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<BalanceInquiryModel>(array);
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                console.log("table data",array)

              }, 
              )
          }



        }
```

```html
            <h3 align="center">Balance Inquiry Most Recent Report</h3>

            <div>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input class="inputSearch" matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>

                <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >
                    <div class="btn-group-export" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <button id="exportBtn1"  (click)="exporter.exportTable('csv', {fileName:'BalanceInquiryRecentReport'}); isClicked1 = true; isClicked2 = false;"  [ngClass]="{'set-color-export': isClicked1 }">Export to csv</button>
                        <button id="exportBtn2"  (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'BalanceInquiryRecentReport'}); isClicked1 = false; isClicked2 = true;" [ngClass]="{'set-color-export': isClicked2 }">Export to xlsx</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="overflow: auto;">

                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matSort matTableExporter    #exporter="matTableExporter" >

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="fingpayTransactionId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fingpay Transaction Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fingpayTransactionId}}</td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="adhaarNumber">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header align="center"> Aadhaar Number </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.adhaarNumber}} </td>
                    </ng-container>


                    <ng-container matColumnDef="phoneNumber">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Phone Number </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phoneNumber}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
            <!--     
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="pan">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> pan</th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.pan}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                 -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="stan">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Stan </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stan}} </td>
                    </ng-container>


                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="iin">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> iin </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.iin}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->

                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="transactionAmount">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> transactionAmount </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.transactionAmount}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
            <!--         
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="track3Data">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> track3Data </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.track3Data}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="cardAcceptorTerminalIdentification">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Card Acceptor Terminal Id</th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardAcceptorTerminalIdentification}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="bcIdentificationCode">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> bcIdentificationCode </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bcIdentificationCode}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="transactionIdentifier">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Transaction Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.transactionIdentifier}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="requestedTimestamp">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Requested Timestamp </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestedTimestamp}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="requestedRemarks">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Requested Remarks </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestedRemarks}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="webStatus">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> WebStatus </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.webStatus}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceImei">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Device Imei </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deviceImei}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantId}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="lastUsedHash">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> lastUsedHash </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastUsedHash}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="responsePan">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responsePan </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responsePan}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseTime">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Time </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseTime}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseDate">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Date </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseDate}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseRrn">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Rrn </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseRrn}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="responseAuthorizationIdentificationResponse">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responseAuthorizationIdentificationResponse </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseAuthorizationIdentificationResponse}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseCode">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Code </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseCode}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="responceCardAcceptorNameOrLocation">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responceCardAcceptorNameOrLocation </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responceCardAcceptorNameOrLocation}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
            <!--         
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseAdditionalAmounts">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responseAdditionalAmounts </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseAdditionalAmounts}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseAddtionalData">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responseAddtionalData </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseAddtionalData}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseAuthenticationCode">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> responseAuthenticationCode </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseAuthenticationCode}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseRemarks">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Remarks </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseRemarks}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantTransactionId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantTransactionId </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantTransactionId}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseAccountIdentification">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Account Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseAccountIdentification}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="resposeTimestamp">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Respose Timestamp </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.resposeTimestamp}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantName">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantName}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="superMerchantName">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Corporate Name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.superMerchantName}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="parentMerchantName">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> parentMerchantName </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.parentMerchantName}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="State">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> State </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.State}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="branchname">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Branch Name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branchname}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="responseCardAcceptorTerminalIdentification">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Response Card Acceptor Terminal Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responseCardAcceptorTerminalIdentification}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="errorMessage">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Staus Message </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.errorMessage}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="bankName">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bank Name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bankName}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantLoginId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Login Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantLoginId}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="branchLoginId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Branch Login Id </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.branchLoginId}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="totalCommission">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> totalCommission </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.totalCommission}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="fingpayRevenue">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> fingpayRevenue </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fingpayRevenue}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
                    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="bankCommission">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> bankCommission </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bankCommission}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="fingpayShare">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> fingpayShare </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fingpayShare}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantShare">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> merchantShare </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.merchantShare}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="serviceType">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> serviceType </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.serviceType}} </td>
                    </ng-container> -->
            <!--         
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="parentId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> parentId </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.parentId}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="superMerchantId">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> superMerchantId </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.superMerchantId}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="threeWaystatus">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> threeWaystatus </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.threeWaystatus}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                     -->


                    <ng-container matColumnDef="latitude">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Latitude </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.latitude}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="longitude">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Longitude </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.longitude}} </td>
                    </ng-container>



                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:   getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>

                </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                <mat-paginator  #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

I'm not able to understand where the error is occurring, mat-paginator is not working properly as well, could it be something to do with that?